# an inequality about kronecker product with eigenvalues question

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently i'm reading a paper,there is a inequality that confuse me. L is a symmetric,irreducible and semi-positive definite matrix with eigenvalues of $0=\lambda_{1}(L)<\lambda_{2}(L)\leq...\leq\lambda_{m}(L)$(counting the multiplicities),P is a positive definite matrix with maximum eigenvalues $\lambda_{m}(P)$,both of them are square matrix,and it satisfied

$$x^{T}(L^{2}\otimes P^{2})x\leq \lambda_{m}(L)\lambda_{m}(P)x^{T}(L\otimes P)x$$

I don't know how to prove this inequality,I have searched many references ,but hardly find any result.Maybe there needs other properties,welcome to point out!

Comment: What precisely is your question?

Comment: sorry ,my question is why this inequality is right,how to prove it?

Comment: it would certainly help if you would tell us in which paper you found this inequality.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469948/an-inequality-about-kronecker-product-with-eigenvalues-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use $L^t \otimes P^t = (L\otimes P)^t$ twice below. The proof follows by observing that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^T(L\otimes P)^2 x}{x^T(L\otimes P)x} = \sup_{z=(L\otimes P)^{1/2}x} \frac{z^T(L\otimes P)z}{z^Tz} \le \sup_{z \neq 0}\frac{z^T(L\otimes P)z}{z^Tz} = \|L\otimes P\|.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Also observe that $\|L\otimes P\| = \lambda_m(L)\lambda_m(P)$ as these are psd.

Comment: is it obvious that $L^2\otimes P^2=(L\otimes P)^2$ ?

Comment: Well, $(AC \otimes BD) = (A \otimes B)(C\otimes D)$, and for fractional powers, we can use this lemma with the eigenvector decomposition of the involved matrices...

Comment: i have understood! thank you very much!